# Can iPhone communicate with JMS?

Tags: iphone, xml, jms

Just wondering if someone knows how to send/receive XML messages between iPhone & [Java Message Service](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-142945.html).

Regards

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you could achieve this - either via the HTTP bridge shipped with MQ (I have done this myself), or using the new MQTT support (you would need to find and compile an MQTT C client for Objective-C yourself though).

Comment: Many thanks andypiper :) How can I know if HHTP bridge is installed on my server or not?

Comment: Sorry andypiper, I was mistaken with MQ :) I meant JMS :)

Comment: what is the JMS provider? WebSphere MQ or something else?

Comment: @AndyPiper is websphere MQ able to accomplish this?

Comment: I have not used WebSphere MQ for about 6 years so you would have to ask someone with current knowledge of the technology.