# MQTT client for iPhone

Tags: iphone, push-notification, mqtt

I am trying to follow this [blog](http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=1599) for building push services for iPhone. The blog uses Android as the working platform,but it can be migrated to iPhone too, provided I get an MQTT client in objective C..which I cant find anywhere. The closest I got to this is :

1. I got a C implementation [here](http://mqtt.org/software) - libmosquitto
2. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957665/can-iphone-communicate-with-jms) says I can use something like an HTTP bridge.

Can anyone please help me exploit these two options ? I dont know the next step to take :(

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP option would not help you in this case as you're not trying to talk to a JMS app via MQ (well - you haven't said that is your goal). Your best bet would be to compile something like libmosquitto or one of the other MQTT clients (see list at http://mqtt.org) for the iPhone. There's now a good example https://github.com/njh/marquette which uses mosquitto's libraries on iOS

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with Objective C at all, but it seems as though you can compile any C code as Objective C. Would this get round your problem?

If you're using gcc, you can force it to compile as Objective C using "-x objective-c".

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using [MQTTKit](https://github.com/mobile-web-messaging/MQTTKit) in my projects. It's fairly easy and straightforward to use.

Comment: How could we send push notifications in MQTT payload

Comment: You'll need to setup an MQTT client in your APNS certified server to listen for a message and send a push notification accordingly.

Comment: @Kiran, I am having trouble subscribing to a topic on a specific server. Any ideas

Comment: It's really impossible for me to tell you anything without seeing your code first :)

Answer (score 0):

For swift you can use the following library : https://github.com/ltg-uic/ios-mqtt-base