# How can I use MQTT in iOS?

Tags: ios, mqtt

Does anyone know if it is possible to use MQTT in iOS development like in Android? Is there  a library or something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MQTT client for iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032124/mqtt-client-for-iphone)

Comment: There's a good example https://github.com/njh/marquette which uses mosquitto's libraries on iOS

Comment: These instructions helped me before: http://inote.apptrek.net/2011/10/howto-compile-native-c-codes-to-a-library-for-ios-development-in-xcode-take-mosquitto-for-an-example/ I have not tried marquette yet, but maybe that is the way to go now.

Comment: You can use [MQTTKit](https://github.com/jmesnil/MQTTKit) . There is an example [here](https://github.com/jmesnil/MQTTExample).

Comment: You can use https://github.com/nsnick/MQTTClient it supports TLS/SSL

Answer (score 4):

Try this. It's much better than mosquitto:
The Paho project provides open-source client implementations of open and standard messaging protocols aimed at new, existing, and emerging applications for Machine‑to‑Machine (M2M) and Internet of Things (IoT).
The Paho MQTT C Client is a fully fledged MQTT client written in ANSI standard C. It avoids C++ in order to be as portable as possible. A C++ layer over this library is also available in Paho.
In fact there are two C APIs. "Synchronous" and "asynchronous" for which the API calls start with MQTTClient and MQTTAsync respectively.

C - http://git.eclipse.org/c/paho/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.c.git
Wrapper - https://github.com/relayr/apple-mqtt-example